# Need Assistance regarding AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift4

I am not able to display the data of my custom table view cell in the table view , I think the error is related to autolayout , need assistance regarding Autolayout .
I hereby provide link for my project - 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxz66v23bftakkb/demo%20Project.zip?dl=0

Comment: Seems like picking up a needle from a haystack.

Comment: I am New to iOS development , I tried to find out the fault but not able to resolve it , I think the error is in Autolayout of DemotableView.xib file !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**1.** Add Vertical Spacing between `label` and `button`.

**2.** Remove Static `height` of your 1st `label`.

**3.** remove static `width` of your 4 `Button`.

**4.** add `Horizontal Spacing` between `buttons`.

**5.** set Equal Width to `Buttons`.

**Link:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/klz9v5vl447rtu4/demo%20Project.zip?dl=0

**For Displaying Data to Button**

```
let arrOptions: [String] = dictionary2[indexPath.row]!

    if indexPath.row == dictionary1.count-1 {
        cell.customizedButton3.isHidden = true
        cell.customizedButton4.isHidden = true

        cell.customizedButton1.setTitle(arrOptions[0], for: .normal)
        cell.customizedButton2.setTitle(arrOptions[1], for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        cell.customizedButton3.isHidden = false
        cell.customizedButton4.isHidden = false

        cell.customizedButton1.setTitle(arrOptions[0], for: .normal)
        cell.customizedButton2.setTitle(arrOptions[1], for: .normal)
        cell.customizedButton3.setTitle(arrOptions[2], for: .normal)
        cell.customizedButton4.setTitle(arrOptions[3], for: .normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your project, just add a vertical space constraint between your `question Label` and one of your `selected` buttons, and your code will works well.

Note that each time you use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, for seeing a correct result you should specify the vertical space, between all of your views inside of tableViewCell.

Comment: The question is displaying fully and options are getting overlapped

Comment: if user ad only `vertical` space between `label` and `button`, still it doesn't work as he . want because 1st label contain static `height` so `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` not work. 2nd thing is `button` width is static and lost of space between them so `button` overlap with each other.

Comment: @Pankil , if i want to display the title stored in my dictionary to buttons , how can i do this ? can you help me regarding this ?

Comment: @Pankil , thanks a lot for your response , but it is showing error , I want to display the option store in the dictionary2 below my question label

Comment: @Sudhir code is fine, you just need to give outlet to your `button`.

Comment: @Pankil , one more doubt I am having , If I want to change the background image of button on selection and at the same time i want to disable the other buttons and i want to change the selection as well , how can we do this ?

Comment: @Sudhir, i am not getting your point. please explain in brief.

Comment: @Pankil , Hey why I am not able to display my options fully in my button text  here is my link to code - https://www.dropbox.com/s/9u0rjlhwmggl01v/dropbox.zip?dl=0